# DiscordAPIError 20012 You are not authorized

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
DiscordAPIError[20012]: You are not authorized to perform this action on this application
```

I have made a bot returning the error:

```
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
DiscordAPIError[20012]: You are not authorized to perform this action on this application
    at handleErrors (/home/runner/Anshu-Saroye-DC-BAOT/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:722:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/runner/Anshu-Saroye-DC-BAOT/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1120:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/runner/Anshu-Saroye-DC-BAOT/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:953:14)
    at async _REST.request (/home/runner/Anshu-Saroye-DC-BAOT/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1266:22)
    at async /home/runner/Anshu-Saroye-DC-BAOT/index.js:47:5 {
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action on this application',
    code: 20012
  },
  code: 20012,
  status: 403,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1153619312507109397/commands'
}
Logged in as Anshu Saroye#0383!
```

and the source code of my bot is

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const keepalive247 = require('./keepalive247.js');
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const prefix = 'io!';

const clientId = 'x';
const token = 'x';
const ADMIN_ID = 'x';

const commands = [
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('gwwin')
    .setDescription('Announce giveaway winner')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('username').setDescription('Username of the winner').setRequired(true)),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('aboutus')
    .setDescription('Display About Us information'),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('rules')
    .setDescription('Display Rules'),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ban')
    .setDescription('Ban a user')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('User to ban').setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('reason').setDescription('Reason for banning')),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('timeout')
    .setDescription('Timeout a user')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('User to timeout').setRequired(true))
    .addIntegerOption(option => option.setName('time').setDescription('Timeout duration').setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('reason').setDescription('Reason for timeout')),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('creator')
    .setDescription('Display creator information')
].map(command => command.toJSON());

  const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
  try {
   console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), {
      body: commands,
    });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'idle',
    activities: [{ name: 'Your Bot Status', type: 'PLAYING' }],
  });
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {

  const { commandName, options } = interaction;

  // Handle interactions based on command name
  if (commandName === 'gwwin') {
    const username = options.getUser('username');
    // Implement logic for '/gwwin' command
  } else if (commandName === 'aboutus') {
    const aboutEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('About Us')
      .setDescription('Put your about us information here.')
      .setColor('#00ff00');
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [aboutEmbed] });
  } else if (commandName === 'rules') {
    const rulesEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Rules')
      .setDescription('Put your rules here.')
      .setColor('#ff0000');
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [rulesEmbed] });
  } else if (commandName === 'ban') {
    const user = options.getUser('user');
    const reason = options.getString('reason') || 'No reason provided';
    // Implement ban command logic here using 'user' and 'reason'
  } else if (commandName === 'timeout') {
    const user = options.getUser('user');
    const time = options.getInteger('time');
    const reason = options.getString('reason') || 'No reason provided';
    // Implement timeout command logic here using 'user', 'time', and 'reason'
  } else if (commandName === 'creator') {
    const creatorEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Creator')
      .setDescription('Garv._Jangre is the creator of this bot.')
      .setColor('#0000ff');
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [creatorEmbed] });
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

and yah prefix is also not working
please help meeeee

I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently working on a Discord bot but have encountered an issue with setting up slash commands. I've been receiving the following error:

```
"DiscordAPIError[20012]: You are not authorized to perform this action on this application."
```

I've ensured that the bot has the necessary permissions and verified the bot token, yet the issue persists. I would greatly appreciate your guidance or any suggestions you might have to fix this problem.

Any insights or advice on resolving this error would be incredibly helpful. Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Best regards,
Garv Jangra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot returning error 20012 on slashing commands registeration - JS SDK 14.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067937/discord-bot-returning-error-20012-on-slashing-commands-registeration-js-sdk-14)